# Bought this plant in Japan. Anyone know the name?

Tags: identification, houseplants, tropical

Bought this plant in Japan but it didn't have a tag indicating the species.

[image: Photograph of dieffenbachia in Japan]

Answer (score 2):

It is a *Dieffenbachia* variety, possibly *Dieffenbachia Reflector* but there are a great many varieties available. It prefers bright light but not sunlight, reasonable humidity levels, temperatures no lower than about 65 deg. F and does not like to be too wet - water only when the surface feels dry to the touch. Further care info here https://www.thespruce.com/dumb-cane-dieffenbachia-definition-1902751